# SoX resample and convert

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sox

I am trying to figure out how to combine two commands in SoX. My master file is 44.1 kHz. I first want to resample this file to 22 kHz and then convert it to mp3/opus/ogg. How can I do this with a single command?

Answer (score 40):

SoX determines the files type by looking at its extension. To adjust the rate of the output file, add the `-r` option to the output files formatting options. From the manual synopsis:

```
sox 
  [global-options]
  [format-options] infile1 [[format-options] infile2] ...
  [format-options] outfile
  [effect [effect-options]] ...
```

Items in brackets are optional, `...` means zero or more of the previous item.

Here is an example of how to perform both actions with one command:

```
sox master.wav -r 22050 out.ogg
```

Alternatively, you could add the rate manipulation to the effects chain:

```
sox master.wav out.ogg rate 22050
```

Comment: Do you need additional libraries for this? I get: `sox FAIL formats: no handler for file extension \`ogg'`

Comment: @AndyW: you can see what audio formats your version of sox was compiled with by running: `sox -h`